# Can The Preview Pane in the MarkdownDeep Markdown Editor be Disabled?

Tags: javascript, markdown, markdowndeep

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project which uses the [MarkdownDeep Editor](http://www.toptensoftware.com/markdowndeep/editor) to add a rich editor on top of a basic markdown input textbox (very similar to the Stackoverflow editor window).

Generally it works great. However, in certain scenarios, I would like to disable the preview window. This is automatically generated below the textarea by MDD. Can this be disabled?

Just to be clear, I know I can use CSS to *hide* the preview. But on some devices it's slow and makes typing painful. I want to entirely *turn off* that feature. I don't see anything in the docs other than how to customize the preview.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [docs](http://www.toptensoftware.com/markdowndeep/editor) it specifically mentions that it is recommended that you have the div preview already in your document because it will be created if it isn't found and consequently, could could a visible page refresh if any re-layout has to occur.

> Note: the associated divs are all optional and if missing, the plugin will create them. However... you might experience the page jumping around during load if you do this. ie: it's recommended to explicitly include them.

Thus from the sounds of this, and that there doesn't appear to be any option to turn it off in the [API](http://www.toptensoftware.com/markdowndeep/api) page I would say no, it's not possible.

Comment: Thanks I was afraid of that. It definitely will create one (but potentially unstyled) if it's not there. Basically it does a jQuery search and if it doesn't find an mdd_preivew object, it does an `append`.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so please mark it as the answer to help other people find it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's an answer in as much as "it's not possible" is the answer. But thanks for the time. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused here: if you don't want the preview, use a regular text area instead of mdd_editor... So, under the scenarios where you don't need the previews, instantiate a plain vanilla editor. What am I missing here?

Comment: I still want the toolbar, just not the preview. Without mdd_textarea would the hot keys still work? Would the toolbar? I'm guessing no.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I was looking for something else on mdd. I recently had this same requirement.
Just comment out the code

```
// Update the DOM
if (this.m_divHtml)
    this.m_divHtml.innerHTML=output;
```

in MarkdownDeepEditor.js